# GraphQL No value was provided for variable

Tags: curl, graphql

I'm trying to do a simple query to a GraphQL API (a server with lacinia) using a variable. I've tried to do it through Postman, and also through the cURL it generates, but both with no success, and I can't figure it out.

I want to pass a value to the query variable `userId`. The cURL command is the following (whitespaces removed for conciseness):

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:3000/api/v0/graphql' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"query": "query ($userId: String!) {user(id: $userId) {id name}}", "variables":{"userId":"d0e96d48-3244-4140-8572-d7085af0cf78"}}'
```

And I got

```
{"errors":[{"message":"No value was provided for variable `userId', which is non-nullable.","locations":[{"line":1,"column":27}],"extensions":{"field":"user","argument":"user.id","variable-name":"userId"}}]}
```

But if I put the UUID string directly as in

```
'{"query": "query ($userId: String!) {user(id: \"0e96d48-3244-4140-8572-d7085af0cf78\") {id name}}", "variables":{"userId":"d0e96d48-3244-4140-8572-d7085af0cf78"}}'
```

it works.

What am I missing?

Thank you.